# In Doctrine, how to ignore specific column from update schema command?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have my **mapped entity** named **Product**, with just two columns: `id` and `name`.

If I add another column manually, i.e. `stock_qty` directly with an SQL statement, the schema update tool **will remote it**, of course.

How can I prevent Doctrine remove my custom columns, not mapped to my entity?

Related issues: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6434

Comment: Write a pull request implementing that feature

Answer (score 2):

You can define either a [onSchemaColumnDefinition](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/events.html#onschemacolumndefinition-event)  or a [onSchemaAlterTableRemoveColumn](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/events.html#onschemaaltertableremovecolumn-event) event and ignore these columns.

***Using the onSchemaAlterTableRemoveColumn Event***

In your bundle, create eg. src/AppBundle/EventListener/MyEventListener.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Event\SchemaColumnDefinitionEventArgs;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Event\SchemaAlterTableRemoveColumnEventArgs;

class MyEventListener
{
    public function onSchemaAlterTableRemoveColumn(SchemaAlterTableRemoveColumnEventArgs $args)
    {
        $tableColumn = $args->getColumn();
        $table = $args->getTableDiff();
        if($table->name == 'tableName' && $tableColumn->getName() == 'columnName') {
            $args->preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, register your event listener in your services:

```
services:
    AppBundle\EventListener\MyEventListener:
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onSchemaAlterTableRemoveColumn }
```

Similar, you could do this:

***Using the onSchemaColumnDefinition  Event***

In your bundle, create eg. src/AppBundle/EventListener/MyEventListener.php:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Event\SchemaColumnDefinitionEventArgs;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Event\SchemaAlterTableRemoveColumnEventArgs;

class MyEventListener
{
    public function onSchemaColumnDefinition(SchemaColumnDefinitionEventArgs $args)
    {
        $tableColumn = $args->getTableColumn();
        $table = $args->getTable();
        if($table == 'tableName' && $tableColumn['Field'] == 'columnName') {
            $args->preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, register your event listener in your **services.yml**:

```
services:
    AppBundle\EventListener\MyEventListener:
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onSchemaColumnDefinition }
```

When running:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

should ignore the specified column(s). ("tableName"."columnName" in this case will not be deleted)

References:

[Doctrine schema events](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/events.html#schema-events)

[Doctrine Event Listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Jannes Botis's answer was very helpful. I had some extra issues with an index and foreign key being removed even though the column was ignored. Also, the down migration continued to try to re-add the column in question.

What follows is my expanded solution, based on the other answer.

```
<?php
namespace App\Listener\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Event\SchemaAlterTableAddColumnEventArgs;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Event\SchemaAlterTableRemoveColumnEventArgs;

class DoctrineListener
{
    protected $ignoreFields;

    public function __construct($doctrineIgnoreFields)
    {
        $this->ignoreFields = $doctrineIgnoreFields;
    }

    public function onSchemaAlterTableAddColumn(SchemaAlterTableAddColumnEventArgs $args)
    {
        $tableDiff = $args->getTableDiff();
        if (in_array($tableDiff->name, array_keys($this->ignoreFields))) {
            $tableName = $tableDiff->name;
            $tableColumn = $args->getColumn();
            if (in_array($tableColumn->getName(), $this->ignoreFields[$tableName])) {
                $columnName = $tableColumn->getName();

                if ($tableColumn->getName() == $columnName) {
                    $tableDiff = $args->getTableDiff();
                    unset($tableDiff->addedColumns[$columnName]);
                    foreach ($args->getTableDiff()->addedIndexes as $index => $addedIndex) {
                        foreach ($addedIndex->getColumns() as $column) {
                            if ($column === $columnName) {
                                unset($tableDiff->addedIndexes[$index]);
                                $args->preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    foreach ($args->getTableDiff()->addedForeignKeys as $index => $foreignKey) {
                        foreach ($foreignKey->getColumns() as $column) {
                            if ($column === $columnName) {
                                unset($tableDiff->addedForeignKeys[$index]);
                                $args->preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function onSchemaAlterTableRemoveColumn(SchemaAlterTableRemoveColumnEventArgs $args)
    {
        $tableDiff = $args->getTableDiff();

        if (in_array($tableDiff->name, array_keys($this->ignoreFields))) {

            $tableName = $tableDiff->name;
            $tableColumn = $args->getColumn();

            if(in_array($tableColumn->getName(), $this->ignoreFields[$tableName])) {
                $columnName = $tableColumn->getName();
                $args->preventDefault();

                unset($tableDiff->removedColumns[$columnName]);
                foreach ($args->getTableDiff()->removedIndexes as $index => $removedIndex) {
                    foreach ($removedIndex->getColumns() as $column) {
                        if ($column === $columnName) {
                            unset($tableDiff->removedIndexes[$index]);
                            $args->preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                }
                foreach ($args->getTableDiff()->removedForeignKeys as $index => $removedForeignKey) {
                    foreach ($removedForeignKey->getColumns() as $column) {
                        if ($column === $columnName) {
                            unset($tableDiff->removedForeignKeys[$index]);
                            $args->preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        ...
        bind:
            $doctrineIgnoreFields:
                'table_a':
                    - 'column_a'
                    - 'column_b'
                'table_b':
                    - 'column_c'
                    - 'column_d'

             

    App\Listener\Doctrine\DoctrineListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onSchemaAlterTableAddColumn }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onSchemaAlterTableRemoveColumn }
```

This solution was tested on symfony 4.4

Answer (score 0):

I had some success using the `postGenerateSchema` with Symfony 6.3 without using deprecated or internal doctrine code.

You can see [the full gist here](https://gist.github.com/Brewal/4a623208e7cd60c4dfb5ab9ab56bcb2e).

This works by manually adding the ignored fields and indexes to the schema, so the migration and validation commands don't try to add them.