# How to prevent doctrine from generating unneeded migrations?

Tags: doctrine, symfony4, symfony-4.2, doctrine-migrations

everyone. I use Symfony 4.2 and following database-first approach and have auto-generated entities; But then I need to do some changes in field definitions in entities but I don't want to affect the database structure. Everything works well but if I try to create a migration, doctrine includes all the differences in migrations, and I find no way to prevent this behaviour. I've tried `schema_filter: ~^migration_versions$~` but somehow it doesn't help.

So the questions: 
1) is it a normal application state on prod when column definitions slightly differ in database and entities?

2) how can I say to doctrine to ignore differences in some tables when creating migrations? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53448034/in-doctrine-how-to-ignore-specific-column-from-update-schema-command/53548294#53548294

Answer (score 0):

When you run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` it will generate a file in your `src\Migrations\` directory. You can edit the generated file to remove whatever you don't want to change before you run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`.

I don't suggest doing this on a production server though, and especially if you do so then you should certainly have a backup of your database.